# Exposure at Default (EAD) models with and without the Credit Conversion Factor (CCF)

Tags: credit-risk, banks, banking-regulations

Exposure at Default (EAD) models with and without the Credit Conversion Factor (CCF). What are the pros and the cons of each, and which one should use a small commercial bank?

Comment: Quite a broad topic but here is a paper that contains comparison of the two approaches and references to some related work: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221716001004#bib0005

Comment: Thanks for the link. Would you say that the trend now is not to use CCF?

Comment: You see both in practice, but it’s hard to model so the simpler the better!